# Atmel studio 7 with Arduino Uno: Just upgraded to Atmel studio 7 and my target platform is the Arduino Uno

Tags: keyboard

Atmel studio 7 with Arduino Uno: 
Just upgraded to Atmel studio 7 and my target platform is the Arduino Uno.

I can't get past the start procedure: Firstly on starting up I get *Sequence contains no elements* (first image below). Then after pressing enter and entering the the *Sketch File* and *Arduino IDE Path* fields, the *Board* and *Device* fields remain empty (second image below).

I'm unable to select or update any of these two fields (*Board* and *Device*) - any assistance is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I also had random problems trying to import Arduino sketches using the new Atmel Studio feature. I eventually gave up. It might just not be ready for prime time yet.

Comment: Do you run the Configuration Manager, upon the first launch? It should run automatically, in fact. I installed AS7 yesterday, using the web installer, and it automatically selected Arduino IDE 1.6.5, and the boards were also selected automatically. Do you actually have the Arduino IDE installed? I assume so, from looking at your screen shot. Try upgrading the IDE and running the Configuration Manager again.

Comment: Do you have [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Arduino-Visual-Studio-Downloads.aspx) installed?